# Running Tornado Documentation locally

Tags: python, tornado, python-sphinx

I am using Facebook's Tornado Framework this week and I am sometimes in areas where the internet is spotty. Since the [website](https://github.com/facebook/tornado/tree/master/website) is in the repo, how do I get it to run locally? Is it under AppEngine?

The first time I ran it I didn't look inside so I just did,

```
python website.py
```

And well that gave the following,

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/wsgiref/handlers.py", line 93, in run
    self.result = application(self.environ, self.start_response)
  File "/Users/phwd/tornado/website/tornado/wsgi.py", line 90, in __call__
    handler = web.Application.__call__(self, HTTPRequest(environ))
  File "/Users/phwd/tornado/website/tornado/wsgi.py", line 107, in __init__
    self.method = environ["REQUEST_METHOD"]
KeyError: 'REQUEST_METHOD'
Status: 500 Dude, this is whack!
Content-Type: text/plain
Content-Length: 59
```

Oh okay, so it is using wsgi.py? I tried calling it from Google App Engine instead,

```
 dev_appserver.py .
```

It started the first page but as soon as I peeked into the main documentation

```
ERROR    2011-10-07 17:26:59,566 dev_appserver.py:3360] Error encountered reading file "/Users/phwd/tornado/website/sphinx/build/html/index.html":
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/Users/phwd/tornado/website/sphinx/build/html/index.html'
INFO     2011-10-07 17:26:59,574 dev_appserver.py:4247] "GET /documentation/index.html HTTP/1.1" 404
```

Is there something I need to be doing with Sphinx to get this documentation working locally under a Tornado Web Server? There is a conf.py file in there so isn't it already setup?

**How to run the website app and what are the necessary dependencies I need to use it?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The repo doesn't include the built HTML for the documentation.  Run `make` in the "tornado/website/" directory.

Also, make sure you have mysqldb installed.

(Why the documentation for a web server requires you to run another, significantly worse web server to read it is beyond me, though.)

Comment: There is no html to do that unfortunately, so I will get the "No rule to make target", in the Makefile it has `sphinx-build -b html $(SPHINXOPTS) sphinx/build/html`, then the next step would be `make html` no?  I am going to try getting the latest version from the master to see if that changes anything. Why the documentation is on a server ? No idea... I was thinking the same thing and here I am. I might end up just using wget on tornadoweb.org out of frustration.

Answer (score 2):

in some code `wsgiref.handlers.CGIHandler().run(app)` is used, then we will have this issue,
replace by code below,it may work.

```
from wsgiref.simple_server import make_server
app = tornado.wsgi.WSGIApplication(
     ...
      )
httpd = make_server('',8000,app)
httpd.serve_forever()
```